# How to use Git on Laravel with Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

Can someone help me using admin Voyager using git?
when I add new changes like new BREADs they don't be readed by GIT because the voyager folder is in vendor.
how to make the new changes readed by git without pushing all the folder ???

Comment: Your question is unclear and also seems to be unrelated to Voyager itself. Are you asking how you can commit the changes that Voyager makes to your database into version control?

Comment: Yes, I need to work from my Local environment So, When I need push my change to server, How to push its changes? Ex. New breads. Git hasn't included Vendor folder and content in my database

Answer (score 1):

Git - as well as SVN, Mercurial, and others - only operates on the filesystem. MySQL and Postgres databases are not technically a part of your project's filesystem, so you can't add those changes to a traditional VCS.

Outside of changing your database from MySQL / Postgres to SQLite (which incidentally *is* stored as a file in your project directory), Git will have nothing to do with your database.

If you ***really*** want to go through the hassle of keeping your database version controlled on the filesystem, then you can potentially look into the following:

1. Create a MySQL dump of everything you want to store. Look into [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) to run a command to import the dump after every push. Update the dump as necessary.
2. Use migrations and seeds to keep a snapshot of your database. Look into webhooks to run the appropriate artisan commands to tear down and re-migrate and seed the database after every push. Update your seeds as necessary.
3. Switch to SQLite. I don't know if this will even work because I don't even know if Voyager is compatible with SQLite.

Outside of that, you should probably look into a deployment process for your database that involves tools like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to manage what you need.