# how to migrate voyager stuff to new deploy instance?

Tags: laravel, voyager

laravel voyager is cool, but how to migrate these tables\setting\breads from development to product instance? especially for those develop once, deploy multiple time, how could it be done gracefully?

as for laravel, the native database migration/seeder is good for this purpose

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using 3rd party tools to generate both migrations and seeds from your existing database tables.

Generate migrations: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Generate seeds: https://github.com/orangehill/iseed

Files like DataRowsTableSeeder.php have already been created by Voyager -
 Iseed will want to overwrite them. If this is not acceptable to you, I have created a fork+pull request which allows you to explicitly specify the file/class name when running Iseed: https://github.com/mattrabe/iseed

Answer (score 2):

For Migration, just create migration and run migrate command.

For BREAD, use [this](https://github.com/DrudgeRajen/voyager-deployment-orchestrator) package which will listen to the Voyager BREAD (ADD, Update, Delete) Events and will generate the respective seeder file.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it currently. Best hope so far is to export key tables such as those for the menus, bread and roles and then import them in production (making sure maintenance mode is on, of course).

Would be great if they could make a way [to store central configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827233/how-to-use-git-on-laravel-with-voyager) in a JSON format of some sort so that it can be included in source control.